# Accessing static array

Tags: php, arrays

How do I access values of a static array in PHP?

```
$anyVar = self::MY_ARRAY['identifier']
```

throws 'unexpected [ after MY_ARRAY' at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing your dollar sign

```
$anyVar = self::$MY_ARRAY['identifier'];
```

FYI, naming variables in uppercase should be reserved to constants by convention.

Comment: Ok, however const MY_ARRAY = array("key" => "value", "key2" => "value2"); doesn't seem to be allowed

Comment: So, whats the naming convention for static varialbes? And why isn't there a final that expresses that a varialbe has a set value that cannot chane anymore? Weired language...

Comment: No need to make the array a constant. Just use lowercase for the variable name. Static variables don't have a naming convention (unless you're part of a team that declares their own).